# Overloaded operator preference

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

Which of the two operators the compiler must prefer here?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    operator char() { return 'A'; }
};

struct B : A
{
    operator auto() { return 'B'; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << B().operator char();
}
```

Clang prints `A` and `GCC` prints `B`:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v6c5Ta9Mf

Comment: The operator in B hides the one in A, so GCC is right.

Comment: @IgorR. `operator auto()` is underspecified. So one *can* argue for both.